# Rails ActiveAdmin display image in has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-api

I have created a Production which has_many Galleries.

```
class Production < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :galleries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :galleries, :allow_destroy => true
  ...
```

A Gallery has_one_attached Photo

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :photo
end
```

In my ActiveAdmin form, I've added a has_many field and a conditional image to be shown.

```
...
f.has_many :galleries, allow_destroy: true do |g|
  g.input :photo, as: :file
  g.input :caption
  if g.object.photo.attached?
    image_tag(g.object.photo.variant(resize: '200x200^'))
  end
end
...
```

The image shows, the problem is the images shows separately from the related field. All uploaded images in the Gallery appear above the entire field - just above the Field Label. Is there any way to keep the related field and example image together in the markup? Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the `:hint` option, e.g.

`g.input :photo, as: :file, hint: image_tag(g.object.photo.variant(resize: '200x200^'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try and surround the conditional with some arbre dsl:

```
li(:class => 'input') do
  label(:class => 'label') { "Preview" }
  div(:class => 'myCustomClass') do
    if g.object.photo.attached?
       # your code
    end
  end
end
```

The rails view helpers (like image_tag) do not always play well with arbre's output buffering.